# Conflicting jquery.min.js

Tags: javascript, joomla

I am using two different modules that both have jquery.min.js in my joomla site.   They are conflicting on my homepage.   How can I distinguish between them for the homepage and for the inside pages where the conflict does not occur?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem before, each module loads its own jQuery and conflicts each other.

The solution i have implemented is installing a plugin that prevents the modules from loading jQuery.js and loads only one. Try one of these, maybe it requires little tweaks to fully work:

[Sc Jquery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/7230)

[jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327)

Answer (score 1):

```
$jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
$jQ("document").ready(function(){


// all the Code for Module X


});
```

Comment: Hello Sir, i have already done this.It did not show any effect, I want like a condition though i can run my js in inside pages not on homepage because it already getting from other module. Any other help would be appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($){

  // code here, you could even use $ here as you like

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

as sushil bharwani said:
you should add `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();</script>` into your header, right after you include jquery.min.js
Also make sure you replace all '$' with 'jQuery' in your JS code.